# Python 2.7 - AI program

Tags: python-2.7

Im making an artificial intelligence program. (of sorts)
so far all it does is, it prints the variable, and replicates itself if the var equals 0. If it equals anything else then it prints the var and asks you to exit. the only problem is, it keeps running itself and my tired eyes cant seem to find out why. can anyone help me figure out why it just keeps running?

heres my code:

```
import os

def AI():
    var = 0

    if var == 0:
        var += 1
        print ("var equals 0")
        filename = raw_input("Name your file: ")
        filesave = raw_input("Location of your file: ")
        fptr = open(filesave + filename, "w")
        fptr.write(AI())
    else:
        print ("var equals " + str(var))
        exit = raw_input("exit?")
AI()
```

Comment: `var` never changes in your code.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean when you say "replicates itself."  Do you mean to be calling the AI function again in fptr.write(AI()) ?

Answer (score 0):

You recursively call AI, and it never gets a chance to reach your else statement. You could do:

```
def AI(initial = True):
    var = 0

    if not initial:
        var = raw_input("exit?")
        print ("var equals " + str(var))

    if var == 0:
        print ("var equals 0")
        filename = raw_input("Name your file: ")
        filesave = raw_input("Location of your file: ")
        fptr = open(filesave + filename, "w")
        fptr.write(AI(False))

AI()
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. although the false at the end needs to be capitalized